# Differences between “NewHope” and “NewHope-simple”

Tags: key-exchange, post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, newhope

The well-known paper described a key exchange (KE) scheme named  "[NewHope](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1092)" on USENIX 2016. The authors then proposed  "[NewHope-Simple](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/1157)" - a PKE/KEM scheme. They also submitted "[NewHope for NIST](http://newhopecrypto.org/)" -  variation of "NewHope-Simple" to the NIST PQC competition. Can anyone summarize:

- Differences between "NewHope" and "NewHope-Simple" (Focus on the rationale, not only compare KE with KEM).
- Differences between "NewHope for NIST" and "NewHope-Simple".